# Custom MIME Reader/Writer

Tags: c#, mime, reader

I have to build an app in c# that receives and sends files in MIME format, but they aren't exactly mails. It respects Mime attributes and separete the objects by boundary tags.
Anyone knows a Helper to parse Mime format to a custom object?

Thanks!

PD: Don't ask why someone choose this format for doing this!

Comment: Take a look at [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/.MimeKit).

Comment: Thanks!
I had looked at it, but it couldn't parse my example. 
Now, in a second look, I realized that my example had missed spaces. 

So, I'll continue looking at it!